# Create/Update in 1:n relationship doesn't work in ASP.net Core 6

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I am learning EF core and I ran into a problem with my first 1:n relationship creation. I auto generated the code for controller and all the CRUD views according to my model.
my model :

```
public class Category
{
    [Key]
    public int CategoryId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string img { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<SubCategory> SubCategories { get; set; } 

}
public class SubCategory
{
    [Key]
    public int SubCategoryId { get; set; }
    public string SubCategoryName { get; set; }

    public string url { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("CategoryId")]
    public int CategoryId { get; set; }
    public virtual Category Category { get; set; }
}
```

I haven't changed anything in the auto generated code yet. Are there any more steps i should do or edit the controller classes before running it?
P.S. Delete and Details work. only Creating and Updating doesn't work

Edit 1:

**categorycontroller**:

```
// GET: Categories/Create
    public IActionResult Create()
    {
        return View();
    }

    // POST: Categories/Create
    // To protect from overposting attacks, enable the specific properties you want to bind to.
    // For more details, see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=317598.
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Create([Bind("CategoryId,Name,img")] Category category)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            _context.Add(category);
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
            return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
        }
        return View(category);
    }

    // GET: Categories/Edit/5
    public async Task<IActionResult> Edit(int? id)
    {
        if (id == null || _context.Categories == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        var category = await _context.Categories.FindAsync(id);
        if (category == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }
        return View(category);
    }

    // POST: Categories/Edit/5
    // To protect from overposting attacks, enable the specific properties you want to bind to.
    // For more details, see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=317598.
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Edit(int id, [Bind("CategoryId,Name,img")] Category category)
    {
        if (id != category.CategoryId)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            try
            {
                _context.Update(category);
                await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
            }
            catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException)
            {
                if (!CategoryExists(category.CategoryId))
                {
                    return NotFound();
                }
                else
                {
                    throw;
                }
            }
            return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
        }
        return View(category);
    }
```

I verified Deleting and Details function by adding data into the db manually. but adding it through this controller doesn't work

Comment: Please share the Update and Creating code

Comment: The `[ForeignKey]` attribute needs to point at the related property. It's a bit odd, but if you put it on the CategoryId property, it should be `ForeignKey("Category")]". If it is on the Category property it would be `[ForeignKey("CategoryId")]`. Beyond that, add the code you are using for Create and Update to identify possible issues there.

Comment: The code is default autogenerated code from scaffolding. I will post it as an edit